# Carthrob on authorize hook extension

Tags: cartthrob, php, php-errors

I am creating an extension to save some data from orders through CT into a new db table.

My code is causing this error message:

> Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int

Here is my code:

```
function cartthrob_on_authorize()
{
    foreach ($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->items() as $item) { 

        // Create array to store member id and purchased upload slots
        $my_data = array(
            'member_id' => $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'),
            'upload_total' => $item->item_options('fees'),
        );

        // Store member id in variable
        $member_id = $my_data['member_id'];  

        // Query table to check if there if record with member id exists
        $query = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id)); 

        // If query returns more than 0 update record 
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            //Find current upload total value   
            $this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
            $upload_total = $this->EE->db->get('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total');  

            // If upload total is more than 0       
            if($upload_total > 0) {

                $new_total = $upload_total + $my_data['upload_total'];  

                $my_data['upload_total'] = $new_total;

            }   

            $this->EE->db->update('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', $my_data);

        // If query returns 0 insert new record         
        } else {

            $this->EE->db->insert('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', $my_data);


        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to PHP, so I could be doing some stupidly wrong (more than likely).

Can anyone take a look and see if I am making any obvious errors here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here:

```
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total');
```

Is getting a result object, not the actual upload_total column. Change it to this to get the actual column value.

```
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total')->row('upload_total');
```